# Error when include new barriers in the graph of a breadth first search

Tags: python, breadth-first-search, psychopy

I'm creating an experiment in PsychoPy in which the participant can move a circle through a 20x10 grid. The participant can also build barriers against a predator that will appear in the grid after 20 seconds and start chasing the circle. The chase is based on a breadth-first search that I included in an "each frame" tab of a code component of the builder. This BFS is based on class "SquareGrid" which includes, as one of its methods, the list of barriers through which nor the predator nor the circle can pass, so the paths will not include these cells of the grid. The BFS returns me a dictionary of paths every frame and, from this dictionary, I recreate the path with the following code, inserted in the same "each frame" tab of a code component:

```
def reconstruct_path(came_from, start, goal):
    current = goal
    path = [current]
    while current != start: 
        current = came_from[current]
        path.append(current)
    path.reverse() # optional
    return path
```

Everything works perfectly with the barriers the participant create before the predator appears, but, if a barrier is created once the chase has already begun, I get the following error message:

```
    current = came_from[current]
KeyError: (75, -225)
```

[(75, -225) is the position where the barrier which led to the error was created]

Would anyone have an idea about what can be the problem? I've started programming a few weeks ago, so I don't know what else I could try. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `came_from` is getting modified during the chase so when you try to access a key that used to be, but is not longer there, you're getting `KeyError`. Look for modifications that you're doing to `came_from`, such as updates and `del`

Comment: Thanks, Dinidu. Even with both the BFS and the came_from being updated every frame? Wouldn't this detect the modifications?

Comment: Also, what do you mean by updates and del? (sorry, I'm really an beginner here...). Thanks again

Comment: lookup: "python dictionary update del" - I'm sure you'll find plenty of examples and explanations

Comment: That's great, thanks!